# JS- to click another button and close a menu on click

Tags: jquery, menu, zurb-foundation

I am building a menu in Foundation 6 and for the lack of better solution I am trying to make the script click on the Moue button once of the menu items was clicked.

```
<div data-sticky-container>
  <div class="small-12 sticky" data-sticky data-options="stickyOn: small" data-margin-top="0">

    <div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="responsive-topbar" data-hide-for="medium">
      <a href="#" class="menu-text show-for-small-only">BB</a>
      <button class="menu-icon float-right" type="button" data-toggle></button>
    </div>

    <div class="top-bar" id="responsive-topbar">
      <div class="top-bar-left">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="menu-text hide-for-small-only">AA</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="top-bar-right">
        <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
          <li><a href="#" class="clicked">One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="clicked">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="clicked">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>

 $('.clicked').click(function(evt) {
    $('.menu-icon').click();
});

</script>
```

Is this script targeting the right element?

```
<script>

     $('.clicked').click(function(evt) {
        $('.menu-icon').click();
    });

    </script>
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: $('.menu-icon').click(); where is this element with class menu-icon? i cant see it in your code...

Comment: Your code seems different from [Foundation's docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/topbar.html#) on how to achieve this - for example, on click the button activating the menu receives a new class, which would be the best way to toggle the menu from active to inactive.

Comment: @AleksandarĐokić there's <button class="menu-icon float-right" type="button" data-toggle></button>

Comment: @Toby Could you tell me how to toggle this class via jQuery? Are you able to write that script because I don't seem able to do it?

Comment: I can't write it for you, only help you troubleshoot your code. Go to the Foundation docs, see if there's something there that does what you need, copy the code and see if you can integrate it into your site.

Comment: @Toby It looks like on click 

<div id="responsive-topbar" class="top-bar" style="display: block;">

an in-line style is toggled from "display: none" to "display:block" - how would I set it back to "display: none"?

Comment: See the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will set the `.top-bar` element to `display: none;`

```
$('.dropdown li a').click(function() {
 $('.top-bar').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: Yes! That solved it!

It also wouldn't work when inserted in the page directly so I moved to the app.js and it did the trick!

Many thanks Toby!!!!

Comment: But... Now the top bar disappears on the desktop version as well!?

Any idea how to limit this for "small" only?l

Comment: I wrapped this script in 

var windowWidth = $(window).width();
if(windowWidth < 768){

$('.dropdown li a').click(function() {
 $('.top-bar').css('display', 'none');
});

}

And it works!

Thanks again!